# Return to GUI without Ctrl+Alt+F7? (my F7 key doesn't work)

Tags: gui, console

my problem is that I can't return to GUI when I am in a console (Ctrl+Alt+F1,2,3...) because a beer destroyed my F7 key. Is there any other way to return to GUI without starting a new one (and having two parallel GUI's running, if that is even posible)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the command line use [chvt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chvt.1.html):

```
chvt 7
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, as it works.